Namespace Issues with TF Frames in Multi-Instance Nav2 Setup (ROS Humble)
I'm working on a project where a master BT activates different navigation BTs based on some conditions. I'm using a custom Nav2Client node in the master BT to call the action server for each navigation BT, which requires launching multiple instances of nav2 with namespaces for differentiation.
However, I'm encountering issues with namespaces. Nav2 expects the odom and map frame IDs to include the namespace (as I understand it). I fixed the issue for the odom frame by setting the /tf and /tf_static remapping to be "absolute" (i.e. keeping the "/") in the nav2 launch file. But, when setting a goal pose, I get the same error for the map frame:
No Transform available: Error looking up target frame "map" passed to lookupTransform. The target_frame does not exist.
I checked the TF tree, and the map and odom frames are present. I'm using ROS Humble and the BT CPP v3 library for the master BT.

Its hard to say since I don't have a full picture of what you're doing from the description. In terms of resources, we have the multi-robot launch files in Nav2 you can use as reference that are functioning examples of Nav2 working with namespaces and multi-robot applications.
In terms of specifics, I usually advise folks to have TF topics (among all others) specific to each robot / instance so that they are completely isolated from each other - as you would do on some hardware robot applications. This is opposed to renaming all your TF topics to include some instance-specific prefix and handling topic collisions with the namespace. The launch files and examples Nav2 provides of multi-robot show this in action with the config files, namespacing, and topic remapping for TF.
I think rather than trying to dissect all the subtle details of your solution, its probably more expedient for you to review Nav2's example (or start from that and modify to your heart's desire) to have an immediate reference of a functioning design that is of my personally recommended architecture. Though, there are other legitimate designs that would work as well.
